# Running loop for frequency calculation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dummy-variable

I have the data as shown in the table. I want to use Python. For all the fruits that exist in the year 2016 and 2017, I want the frequencies of country in 2015 for those fruits.

| Country | Fruit | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Apple | 2015 |
| France | Apple | 2015 |
| France | Apple | 2015 |
| Spain | Apple | 2015 |
| Germany | Banana | 2015 |
| France | Banana | 2015 |
| France | Apple | 2016 |
| Spain | Apple | 2016 |
| Germany | Banana | 2016 |
| France | Banana | 2016 |
| France | Banana | 2017 |
| France | Grapes | 2017 |

The final table I want looks like below:

| Fruit | Germany | France | Spain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Banana | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Grapes | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Where is the Python code? do you have an initial attempt to solve this? If so, please include it in the question. Otherwise, StackOverflow is not a site to solve problems that users have not given an inital attempt or shown where in their code they are having difficulties.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't know. Will keep in mind from next time. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, everything is in the [tour], and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by Year and then pivot it with `pivot_table`:

```
(df[df.Year == 2015]
  .pivot_table('Year', 'Fruit', 'Country', aggfunc='count')
  .reindex(
    index=df.Fruit.unique(), 
    columns=df.Country.unique()
  ).fillna(0)
  .reset_index())

Country   Fruit  Germany  France  Spain
0         Apple      1.0     2.0    1.0
1        Banana      1.0     1.0    0.0
2        Grapes      0.0     0.0    0.0
```

---

Another option is to use `crosstab` and then select 2015 from the result:

```
(pd.crosstab(df.Fruit, [df.Country, df.Year])
   .loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 2015]]
   .droplevel(1, 1)
   .reset_index())

Country   Fruit  France  Germany  Spain
0         Apple       2        1      1
1        Banana       1        1      0
2        Grapes       0        0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df_2015 = df[df['Year'] == 2015]
pd.crosstab(df_2015['Fruit'], df_2015['Country']).reindex(df['Fruit'].unique(), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Country  France  Germany  Spain
Fruit                          
Apple         2        1      1
Banana        1        1      0
Grapes        0        0      0
```